# Dynamic form fields in Rails3 with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rialscasts #74 as a guide.

I am trying to dynamically add form fields via a text-link. In the railscast episode he achieves it very nicely using the following code:

```
<!-- layouts/application.rhtml -->
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

<!-- projects/new.rhtml -->
<div id="tasks">
  <%= render :partial => 'task', :collection => @project.tasks %>
</div>
<p><%= add_task_link "Add a task" %></p>

<!-- projects/_task.rhtml -->
<div class="task">
<% fields_for "project[task_attributes][]", task do |task_form| %>
  <p>
    Task: <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
    <%= link_to_function "remove", "$(this).up('.task').remove()" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
</div>

 # projects_helper.rb

 def add_task_link(name)
    link_to_function name do |page|
      page.insert_html :bottom, :tasks, :partial => 'task', :object => Task.new
    end
 end
```

content within projects_help.rb is what I am most interested in. The problem is he is doing this via prototype. I am looking for an exact duplicate implementation using jquery (and rails3). What do you think? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ya I was going to say --  that is a very old railscast and is using both outdated practices and an old framework.  I'm gonna try to help you out.

layouts/application.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

projects/new.erb

```
<div id="tasks">
  <%= render :partial => 'task', :collection => @project.tasks %>
</div>
<p><%= add_task_link "Add a task" %></p>
```

projects/_task.erb

```
<div class="task">
<!-- I think this part should still work -->
<%= fields_for "project[task_attributes][]", task do |task_form| %>
  <p>
    Task: <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
    <!-- We're going to be defining the click behavior with unobtrusive jQuery -->
    <%= link_to "remove", "#", :class => 'remove_task'
  </p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

projects_helper.rb

```
def add_task_link(name)
  # This is a trick I picked up... if you don't feel like installing a
  # javascript templating engine, or something like Jammit, but still want
  # to render more than very simple html using JS, you can render a partial
  # into one of the data-attributes on the element.
  #
  # Using Jammit's JST abilities may be worthwhile if it's something you do
  # frequently though.
  link_to name, "#", "data-partial" => h(render(:partial => 'task', :object => Task.new)), :class => 'add_task'
end
```

public/javascripts/application.js

```
$(function(){
  // Binds to the remove task link...
  $('.remove_task').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.task').remove();
  });

  // Add task link, note that the content we're appending
  // to the tasks list comes straight out of the data-partial
  // attribute that we defined in the link itself.
  $('.add_task').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tasks').append($(this).data('partial'));
  });
});
```

Comment: My data-partial is coming out unescaped and screwing up the rendering of elements everywhere. Is there something I'm missing here or doing wrong? It seems to be not rendering correctly, at least with Rails 3.1

Comment: @DFischer did you make sure to put the h() around the render in that attribute?  I've noticed that sometimes that doesn't quite work for some reason, and my work-around was to do this:  `h(render(stuff_here) + '')`.  I suspect the problem is that render() gets flagged as html_safe, and then h() is run and sees it's html safe so decides not to escape it for some reason. Appending an empty string will make it no longer html_safe so hopefully that works :)

Answer (score 5):

The current RailsCasts/ASCIICasts are #196 (see http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) & 197 which have been updated for Rails3.

Ryan Bates has also created a gem called nested_form (see https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) which handles much of this for you. He has has also created examples of complex nested forms using Prototype, jQuery, and his nested form gem; you can find a link on the nested_forms page.

Good stuff!