# Create form fields for hash attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Product, which has a properties attribute. It stores it in a single database column as a hash (following http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :properties
end
```

How can I create dynamic form fields for this property attribute (which is a hash)? I'm interested in ideologically correct way of doing this ("rails way"). I guess that there is need to use fields_for helper. But I do not fully understand how to do it. Tell me the correct way of solving this problem, please.

In result, I'd like to get a working form like shown on image.

[image]

Where a user can add unlimited number of fields and give any property names and its values.

Comment: How do you want it to look? What choices will the user have? Do you pre-define the keys, and they fill in the values, or is it free-form?

Comment: You can inspire by: (1) http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms  (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917691/dynamic-form-fields-in-rails3-with-jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rails way needn't include the limitation of using a single table, ideally, you can do this in a very rails way with 2 tables. Moving on.

You shouldn't use Active Record `:store` for this purpose in my opinion.

That implementation is ideal for situations where the developers need to store model metadata that is flexible in-code but well-defined at any given point of time. Which is to say, you need to specify keys in the model.

There is another pit-fall, you can't run SQL queries on the resulting serialized text that is saved.

If you insist, you can do this:

In your model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :properties

  def prop_hash
    self.properties.collect{|k,v| [k,v]}
  end

  def prop_hash=(param_hash)
    # need to ensure deleted values from form don't persist        
    self.properties.clear 
    param_hash.each do |name, value|
      self.properties[name.to_sym] = value
    end  
  end

end
```

In the view:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <% f.object.prop_hash.each do |k,v| %>
    <%= text_field 'product[prop_hash][][name]', k %>
    <%= text_field 'product[prop_hash][][value]', v %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can also add an 'add another property' link which should use JS to insert another pair of inputs with the names `product[prop_hash][][name]` and `product[prop_hash][][value]` respectively.

Long ago I had rolled a custom implementation for metadata which saves the keys in serialized XML, for one reason - it can be queried in SQL. The link to my blog article http://geniitech.tumblr.com/post/14916592782/storing-metadata-as-xml-hash-in-ror

Answer (score 0):

To be brief, you want to have a form that contains this within it somewhere:

```
<% @product.properties_hash.each do |k,v| %>
  <%= f.field_for k %>
  <%= f.field_for v %>
  <# link to action that will remove this key/value pair from the serialized hash saved in the database %>
<% end -%>
```

You're going to have to create a blank key and value pair somehow (either here in the form just using the form helpers or by adding a blank(ish) key and value pair to the end of the hash itself by modifying the `product` in the controller after you load it into @product (like with a @product.add_blank_properties method).  Otherwise you won't have 'blank' fields at the end of the loop. . .

I could go into more detail about adding a new blank line for a property after you create one using the previously existing blank line, but by the time you get this far you should have a good grasp on what you need to look for to solve that (and there are plenty of resources out there (you will probably be using `ajax` for this).

Answer (score -2):

I think you should be using rails standard `scaffold` but here you may need few customization's.

1) Need to declare `resourceful route` for properties
`property name` will become `resource id`
2) `Index view` will iterate over properties `hash` to populate relevant fields.

```
product.properties.each do |name, value|
   puts name
   puts value
end
```

2) `Create` action should create a record if doesn't exist (based on name) already otherwise give an error

```
product.properties[:price] = 10
```

3) `Update` will find property based on name and update it hash way

```
product.properties[:price] = 25
```

4) `delete` will actually delete the `key-value` pair from hash based on property `name`

```
product.properties.delete(:price)
```